# Ведется подготовка

Tags: грамотная-речь

Деловой язык не всегда литературный. Грамотно ли писать  "ведется подготовка" с точки зрения литературного языка. Если нет - помогите подобрать синонимы

Answer (score 2):

А почему нет? Ведётся - производится, осуществляется.

Ведется подготовка к концерту Мадонны - осуществляются подготовительные работы по организации концерта.

В Твери ведется подготовка к конкурсу на участие в областной Программе поддержки местных инициатив: во всех районах города проводятся собрания, на...

Ведется подготовка к коллегии департамента образования автономного округа.

В РФ ведётся подготовка к модернизации Т-80БВ » Военное обозрение
topwar.ru/103700-v-rf-vedetsya-...

Ведётся подготовка к традиционному карнавалу в Кабардинке

Ведется подготовка к строительству дома.

Answer (score 1):

**Официально-деловой стиль** является одним из стилей русского литературного языка, они не противопоставлены друг другу.

Поэтому сочетание "**ведется (осуществляется)  подготовка**" соответствует нормам литературного русского языка, но  применяется в основном в книжной речи.

**ВЕСТИ** 9. что. Заниматься какой-л. деятельностью, выполнять какие-л. обязанности; **производить, осуществлять**. В. хозяйство, научную работу. В. войну, борьбу с кем-л. В. подкоп. В. разговор. В. переписку. В. дневник, журнал. В. кружок, семинар (быть его руководителем). В. собрание (председательствовать).

**Примеры:**

В институте  **ведется подготовка** научных кадров высшей квалификации. Обществом приобретена лицензия и **ведется подготовка** к разработке  буроугольного месторождения.  **Ведется подготовка** списков участников предстоящего референдума.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "ведётся подготовка" корректно и косвенно ссылается на людей, под руководством которых "идёт" эта самая подготовка: раз она "**ведётся**", значит, **её** осознанно "**ведут**" неназванные ответственные лица, т. е. *всё под контролем*, и это звучит убедительнее варианта "**идёт**" (как бы "сама собой" - не ясно, отвечает ли кто-либо за её ход и сроки).